# How cancel scheduled jobs using BreeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, job-scheduling, nodejs-server

I have an express server that starts a reoccurring job upon client request for a specified amount of time, the issue I'm facing is: How can I stop and remove that specific job after completion.

The code that I have is

```
// do the request logic
// generate the job ID
// save the job ID with repetition amount in mongoose
bree.add({
    name: jobID,
    interval : "30s",
    path : "./jobs/example_job.js",
    worker: {
    workerData: {
        jobID: jobID,
        }},
    })
bree.start(jobID)
```

and for the example_job.js

```
const thread = require("worker_threads") // for the jobID

// performs some logic
// reduce repetition amount
if(module.repetitionAmout == 0)
{
// delete the mongoose module
// stop the function with name jobID
}
```

My issue is with // stop the function with name jobID.
how can I achieve that?
I've tried process.exit(0) but that only exits the thread and doesn't stop it from repeating again
I've also tried exporting and importing the bree instance to the example_job.js and passing the jobID to cancel it there but that also did not work, anyone has any experience with canceling jobs?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by setting a message handler using `workerMessageHandler` instance option. You can read more about instance options here: https://github.com/breejs/bree#instance-options.

Inside the worker thread you can send messages to the parent thread via `parentPort.postMessage`. When you initialize the Bree object, you can provide a function to handle the messages sent from the worker threads by using the `workerMessageHandler` instance option.

In the example below, I am able to control the number of iterations a job cycles through by sending a message from the worker to the parent thread during each cycle of the job. I am also able to see the thread ID for each worker  thread by setting the `outputWorkerMetadata` option to `true`.

**main.js**

```
import Bree from 'bree';

let sofar = 0;
const limit = 10;

const handler = (msg) => {
  let threadId = bree.getWorkerMetadata(msg.name).worker.threadId;
  console.log(`Iteration ${++sofar}: ${msg.message} thread ${threadId}`);
  if (sofar === limit) {
    bree.stop();
    console.log("limit reached, stopped bree...");
  }
}

const bree = new Bree({
  logger: false,
  jobs: [{
    name: 'test',
    interval: 3000,
    path: './test.js'
  }],
  workerMessageHandler: handler,
  outputWorkerMetadata: true
});

await bree.start()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("started bree...")
  });
```

**test.js**

```
import { parentPort } from 'worker_threads';

parentPort.postMessage('message from worker');
```

**example output**

```
started bree...
Iteration 1: message from worker thread 1
Iteration 2: message from worker thread 2
Iteration 3: message from worker thread 3
Iteration 4: message from worker thread 4
Iteration 5: message from worker thread 5
Iteration 6: message from worker thread 6
Iteration 7: message from worker thread 7
Iteration 8: message from worker thread 8
Iteration 9: message from worker thread 9
Iteration 10: message from worker thread 10
limit reached, stopped bree...
```